# A question about the golden ratio and other numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Suppose that $$c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+ \cdots = \frac{1} {\lfloor{r}\rfloor+\lfloor{2r}\rfloor  x+\lfloor{3r}\rfloor x^2+ \cdots},$$
where $r = (1+ \sqrt{5})/2$.  Let $i_0 < i_1 < i_2 < \cdots $ be the numbers $i$ for which $c_i \ge 0.$  Is $i_j  = 2j$ for every $j$?

For what other choices of $r$ is $i_j  = 2j$ for every $j$?

(Added on Jan. 4, 2017) Here are some initial terms: 
$$ (c_0,c_1,c_2, \dots) = (1, -3, 5, -9, 17, -30, 52, -90, 154, -262, 446, -758, 1285, \dots ).$$  The first question is this:  do the signs alternate for the whole sequence?  The second question may lead to some surprises.

Comment: This should work for $r=F_{t+1}/F_t$ for $t\geq5$; where $F_t$'s are the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Sequence $\lfloor nr\rfloor$ in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A000201

Comment: Could you please write out the first few terms in this expansion?

Comment: My guess would be: this is true for any real number $r$ between $3/2$ inclusive and $5/3$ exclusive.  (This is an experimental observation, I don't have a proof.)